# rendering pandas dataframe ot html with highlighted cells

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have a pandas daraframe which I am rendering to html:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['parm A'] = [9.5, 8.2, 13]
df['parm B'] = [True, False, True]


html = df.to_html()
path = "C:\\path"
file_name = "file.html" #make file name specific to patient and plan name
text_file = open(file_name, "w")
text_file.write("df Parameters \n" + html)
text_file.close()
```

The dataframe contains a combination of floats and booleans. The goal is to render the dataframe using a set of conditions. In this specific dataframe, floats will be highlighted green if less than 10 and red if greater than 10. Also, cells that contain True will be green and False will be red:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution would be to use pandas styling, here goes:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['parm A'] = [9.5, 8.3, 13]
df['parm B'] = [True, False, True]

def red_green(s):
    return ['background-color: green' if (v<10 and v) else 'background-color: red' for v in s]

html = df.style.apply(red_green).render()
path = "C:\\path"
file_name = "file.html" #make file name specific to patient and plan name
text_file = open(file_name, "w")
text_file.write("df Parameters \n" + html)
text_file.close()
```